# Trying to setup a redirect to app using Universal Links but nothing is happening

Tags: ios, swift

So I have the following apple-app-site-association on my site, located at `stage.domain.com/apple-app-site-association`:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "TEAMID.application.id.goes.here",
        "paths": ["*"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've set my Associated Domains as `applinks:stage.domain.com`

But when I try to navigate to `stage.domain.com` in Safari, it doesn't register and I stay in the browser. Is there anything else I need to do? I know that I need to eventually set routing up in the app for various pages, but that isn't a necessary requirement is it? It should just pull up the app without anything else? Or am I missing something?

Also, my restoration handler:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

    print("DEBUG GETS TO NSURL?")

    guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
        let url = userActivity.webpageURL

        else
    {return false}

    print("DEBUG GETS TO URL")

    return true
}
```

It gets to neither debug condition.

Comment: When you access your site, does it show the universal links banner on top of the page? Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSQGK.jpg

Comment: Yes it does. I do see that banner.

Comment: Why, is there something that that means?

Comment: So, you are doing it right. If you click on Open, it should open the app. Then, if you try to click on a link to your website AFTER you opened your app through the banner, iOS should save your preferences and open the app directly, instead of going to Safari with the banner on top.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this automatically? I'm trying to go to a Safari browser instance and then immediately redirect to the app

Comment: The way Universal Linking works, it does not allow the app to be opened by links without any consent of the user. Thus, the user must give permission at least one time before the app opens automatically.

Comment: Hrm, this is a major problem then, I'm trying to record the same user agent data from the browser before and after.

Comment: Still if you're right you've answered my question, feel free to give this as an answer for points

Comment: Created an answer with my comments. I feel you, I have been through the same... But it makes sense in a way, for security reasons, users should decide whether or not they want the app to be opened.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander I understand that you want the deep link to automatically close safari and go back to your app. The deep link would work perfectly as expected in android but in iOS it needs the user to press a confirmation button to go back to the app. I am using firebase and in my app the user has to press Ok on my dynamic link but in Android same dynamic link works without user interaction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you already go through the debugging steps here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1916/_index.html

I found the validation tool linked to in step one of the diagnostic section of the above reference to be quite helpful.  It will verify that you set the app association file up correctly, and often give some guidance if you didn’t.

### Update:

Based on your comment below regarding the link not working in Safari, I'd suggest verifying that your universal link setting for that domain didn't get disabled on your test device.

Specifically:

- If a user opens a universal link and is taken to the app, there is a shortcut in the top right of the status bar which, if tapped, takes the user to the web version of the link *and also disables the universal link opening the app*.  To re-enable the universal link for your app, you can paste the link into an app like Notes or Messages, long press on it, and choose "Open in... [Your App]".
- The other possibility is that your web page in Safari is trying to open the universal link via Javascript or wrapped in a redirect.  Neither of these will work.

There are more details in this blog post, along with some other universal link issues:  https://medium.com/mobile-growth/the-things-i-hate-and-you-should-know-about-apple-universal-links-5beb15f88a29

### Additional Update:

I have a suspicion regarding your scenario: Apple does not trigger a universal link when the user directly types a URL to a universal link domain into the Safari address bar. The assumption being that if the user explicitly entered a URL into the Safari address bar, the correct response is to open the URL in Safari.  In this scenario, Safari inserts the banner that allows the user to intentionally open the link in the app to the top of the page.

You can test this yourself:

1. Install the Twitter app
2. Paste the URL to a tweet in Safari's address bar.  Note that it opens the tweet page in the browser. Tap the banner with the "Open" link at the top of the page to open it in the Twitter app.
3. Open Safari again.  Now Google the word "tweet" or otherwise find a page that has a *link* to a tweet (rather than typing or pasting the URL in the Safari address bar)
4. Note that tapping the link opens the Twitter app instead of the page in Safari.

Comment: Yes I’ve used it. It says my entitlements are not setup, even though they absolutely are. They’re added to my App ID in Apple Developer as well as my associated domains section, where I have applinks:stage.domain.com, which is also currently alive in the newest app version as well

Comment: The app works when I click on it in the email. But it doesn't work in Safari.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander Updated answer with some additional possibilities

Comment: Nope, this doesn't seem to work. The email part works, as does clicking in it on notes, but trying to click a link in Safari does not pull up the app.

Comment: Ok, ACTUALLY, it is because if you are doing it from the same domain it opens it up in Safari, instead of the App.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander  I think I know what an underlying cause may be for your issue. Please see the latest update in my answer

Comment: Yep, this is it.

Comment: what is meaning of can not parse the associated domain file ?

Answer (score 2):

If, when you access your site, it shows the universal links banner on top of the page, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSQGK.jpg, you are doing it right.

If you click on Open, it should open the app. Then, if you try to click on a link to your website AFTER you opened your app through the banner, iOS should save your preferences and open the app directly, instead of going to Safari with the banner on top.

The way Universal Linking works, it does not allow the app to be opened by links without any consent of the user. Thus, the user must give permission at least one time before the app opens automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried below code in your app : ***info.plist***

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>stage</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Then open safari type "**stage://**" and press **Go**. It'll redirect you to your app.

Comment: It makes the user select a prompt telling them to go back to the app. I don’t want that. I’ve tried URL schemes before

Comment: is your apple-app-site-association file is upload at the root of your HTTPS server?

Comment: Are you sure? TomsiMac:~ tom$ curl https://stage.domain.com/apple-app-site-association
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>404 Error - Page Not Found</title>
  ...

Comment: i have tried url schema but url removes the :// chars. any solution ?

Answer (score -3):

Usually universal links end with `://`, so try using this URL for your example:
`applinks://stage.domain.com`.

Comment: Are you sure? Look at this image for example: https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2016/04/Associated_Domains.png