# Universal links not redirecting to app but site is approved

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

On my React Native application I set up correctly the deep linking

```
const config = {
  screens: {
    AppNavigator: {
      screens: {
        HomeComponent: 'home',
        Component1: 'test/:id',
        Component2: 'test/:page/:id',
      },
    },
  },
}
const linking = {
  prefixes: ['myapp://', 'https://com.myapp.test'],
  config,
}
```

I believe they are correct because if I run the command `npx uri-scheme open myapp://home` I'm redirected to the right page.

Next I set up the Associated Domains on Xcode and my

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:myapp.page.link</string>
        <string>applinks:myapp.page.link</string>
        <string>applinks:myapp.com?mode=developer</string>
        <string>applinks:*.myapp.com?mode=developer</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I added the `developer` flag because I'm testing it on my phone connected to Xcode in developer mode.

I then added the `apple-app-site-association` file to my server on the `.well-known` subfolder:

```
  "applinks": {
    "defaults": {
      "caseSensitive": false
    },
    "details": [
      {
        "appIDs": [
          "1111111111.com.myapp.test",
          "1111111111.com.myapp.test.test",
        ],
        "components": [
          {
            "/": "/test/*"
          },
          {
            "/": "home"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and if I check the logs on the phone on the `swcutil_show.txt` file I see the following log:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Service:              applinks
App ID:               1111111111.com.myapp.test
App Version:          408.0
App PI:               <LSPersistentIdentifier 0x149e36c70> { v = 0, t = 0x8, u = 0x328, db = 617262B3-586B-49F1-8832-EF960F7380F8, {length = 8, bytes = 0x2803000000000000} }
Domain:               myapp.com?mode=developer
Patterns:             {"/":"/test/*","caseSensitive":false}
User Approval:        unspecified
Site/Fmwk Approval:   approved
Flags:                developer
Last Checked:         2022-01-11 17:20:26 +0000
Next Check:           2022-01-16 17:00:15 +0000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, when I press on a url on the Apple Note app, I land on the website but I'm not redirected to the app.

Any input is well appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951419/trying-to-setup-a-redirect-to-app-using-universal-links-but-nothing-is-happening Try this solution

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the url without "www"?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).